# How to detect direction of rotation?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation, linear-algebra

I have a character with a camera behind him. The head of the character rotates with the `LookAt` function on the character's head rig.

The `LookAt` is done towards targets that may be to the right or left of the entire body of the transform character.

So I want to detect when the head rotates clockwise with respect to the controller body and when it rotates counterclockwise. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question currently is too vague. What does "detect if it rotates the head to the right or to the left" mean? Are you asking how to make the head look at something? How to determine what direction the player is turning the camera?

Comment: how to detect if the rotation is to right or to left..In short, I would like a way to calculate if the head rotates clockwise or counterclockwise

Comment: What is causing the head to rotate? We need to know what input we're using to compute this output. When in doubt, show us your code, a screenshot, diagram, animation - anything you can to make it clear to folks who have never seen your game before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as soon as I get home I post the code.
The head rotates with the Look.at function on the character's head rig.
The Look.at is done towards targets that may be to the right or left of the entire body of the transform character. So I want to detect when the head rotates clockwise with respect to the controller body and when counterclockwise.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have the `Transform` for your `target` object, and the `Transform` of the `body` the head is attached to, you can compute whether it's on the left or right side of the body by looking at the sign of the dot product:

```
Vector3 toTarget = target.position - body.position;
float dot = Vector3.Dot(toTarget, body.right);

if (Mathf.Approximately(dot, 0f)) {
    // Target is straight ahead.
} else if (dot > 0f) {
    // Target is to the right (head rotates clockwise when viewed from above).
} else if (dot < 0f) {
    // Target is to the left (lead rotates counter-clockwise when viewed from above).
}
```

You can also compare against the head's `.right` vector if you want to know whether it's to the left or right of your current look direction, before you update to look at the target. That would let you detect when you're looking to the right but rotating incrementally forward (counter-clockwise) to follow a target that's moving to get in front of you.